# Abracon AB1805 RTC IC - additional resistance on VBAT pin?

Tags: resistance, rtc, low-battery

I intend to use Abracon AB1805 RTC in designed device, powered by a CR2032 battery. IC datasheet contains a note: * Total battery series impedance = 1.5k ohms, which may require an external resistor

[image: RTC schematic]

The CR2032 battery has an impedance of about 20 ohms, so the note indicates that I should add a 1.5K resistor between the + battery and the VBAT IC pin ??

It is a bit strange for me because virtually no power source for RTC (coin battery, supercapacitor) has impedance even close to 1.5K.

Even on the Abracon evaluation board schematic, I do not see any additional resistor on the VBAT pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bit unusual - I suspect it is to control the charge current to the backup source if it is a supercap.

The data sheet doesn't seem to give any insight.

Many batteries, including CR2032 type cells, are limited in the capability for accepting current being injected. One of the other configurations where the power is applied to the RTC using VCC with a FET to isolate the RTC when no primary power is available would seem to be better when a lithium-cell is used as backup.

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to use a low leakage diode ( e.g. BAS116, 5nA reverse current ) to avoid current injection to the battery ?

Comment: @TomaszDzikuć - That may be a good solution, I agree.